# upload pandas dataframe to azure blob without creating csv local file

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have dataframe df that need to be loaded to Azure blob as csv without creating csv file on local.Azure function need to be developed.

Answer (score -1):

First, convert data to .csv:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Then you can use Blob output binding to achieve your requirement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python#example